# Wrong EntityFramework version is being installed

Tags: entity, nuget

From the Package Manager Console I do this:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0
```

And then I right-click on the Reference and I see it is version 4.4.0.0. Doing an uninstall and then installing doesn't help.

This happens for 1 project in the solution, in another project it installs the correct version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the Project was .NET 4.0, once I upgraded it to 4.5 it installs the correct version.